# Terminating condition is given still throwing Stack OverFlow Error

Tags: java, error-handling, runtime-error

trying to solve a question on the leetcode coding platform in which I've started getting with this.

```
class Solution {
public double myPow(double x, int n) {

    // return Math.pow(x, n);

    if(x == 1){
        return 1;
    }

    if(n == 0){
        return 1;
    }

    if(n > 0){
        return positivePow(x, n);
    }
    else{
        return positivePow(1/x, -n);
    }

    
}

public double positivePow(double x, int n){
    
    if(n == 1){
        return x;
    }

    if(x < -10000 || x > 10000){
        return 0;
    }

    if(n % 2 == 0){
        return positivePow(x * x, n / 2);
    }
    else{
        return x * positivePow(x, n - 1);
    }
}
}
```

it should be terminated because of this condition but still throwing stack overflow error for the testcase

x = 2.00000
n = -2147483648

```
if(x < -10000 || x > 10000){
    return 0;
}
```

in the `positivePow` function.

We can only use double as datatype for `x` and the constraints are

- -100.0 < x < 100.0
- -231 <= n <= 231-1
- n is an integer.
- Either x is not zero or n > 0.
- -104 <= xn <= 104

Comment: Well, either `return 1 / positivePow(x, -n);` is wrong or the fact that `positivePow` can return `0` is wrong. Because both of those combined lead to a typical division through zero error.

Comment: Thanks for being this fast I also have improved the change you've suggested but now for the test case
x = 2.0000
n = -2147483648

the stack is being overflowed.

Answer (score 0):

you should change this line `return 1 / positivePow(x, -n)` to `return positivePow(1/x, -n)`

to avoid division by 0, when positivePow returns 0.

also check this solution

```
public double myPow(double x, long n) {
    if(n == 0) return 1;
    if(n < 0) return myPow(1/x, -n);
    if(n % 2 == 1) return x * myPow(x * x, (n-1)/2);
    else return myPow(x * x, n/2);
}
```